# Sort hash by length of contained values

Tags: ruby

Say I have a hash like:

```
foo = {
  :bar => ['r', 'baz'], # has a total str length of 4 characters inside of the array
  :baz => ['words', 'etc', 'long words'] # has a total str length of 18 characters inside of the array,
  :blah => ['at'] # has a total str length of 2 characters inside of the array
  # etc...
}
```

How would I go about sorting this hash by the total string length of the items contained within the arrays? The resulting hash order in this case should be: `:blah, :bar, :baz`

Comment: What do you mean by "sorting hash"?

Comment: Imagine for a second Ruby cannot help you. What would you do then?

Comment: @alf I guess I'd be SOL...but how does pointing that out help me?

Comment: @nonowarn in 1.9.x, hashes are sorted by the order of insertion. I don't know if that's what the OP wants

Comment: @luis.parravicini Yeah, 1.9.x rocks. but I think it's too implicit for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd just do this:

```
Hash[foo.sort_by { |k, v| v.join.length }]
```

I assume you're not intending the change the original Hash values, just re-order them.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, hashes are not ordered, and therefore not sortable.  Ruby 1.9 hashes are ordered, but the language provides no easy way to re-order the elements.  Just like in 1.8, sorting a hash returns an array of pairs:

```
{ c:3, a:1, b:2 }.sort => [ [:a,1], [:b,2], [:c,3] ]
```

(Actually, 1.8 would blow up on that because symbols aren't comparable in 1.8, but never mind.)

But as long as you're OK with the list of pairs, you can sort a hash (or an array) by anything you like.  Just use sort_by and pass a block that extracts the sort key, or use sort with a block that does the comparison:

```
foo.sort_by { |key, strings| strings.join.length }
```

or, if you want the longest ones first:

```
foo.sort_by { |key, strings| -strings.join.length }
```

Then, if you're using 1.9 and want to turn the result back into a Hash, you can do so thus (thanks, Jörg W Mittag):

```
Hash[ foo.sort_by { |key, strings| strings.join.length } ]
```

...which is the same answer as d11wtq.

Comment: `Hash::[]` takes exactly the sort of key-value arrays that all the other `Hash` methods produce, so, if you want to `map` or `sort` or `sort_by` a `Hash`, you just wrap the entire expression in `Hash[…]` to get back a `Hash`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   foo.sort_by { |_,v| v.reduce(:+).size }
```

Comment: Even `reduce(:+)` is enough. However this sorts by string (alphabetical), not by string length.

Comment: @Casper you are right. I've edited the answer to use the string length.

Answer (score 1):

Hash doesn't ensure the order of keys in its concept. But in Ruby 1.9, [Hash's key order is saved](http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/). So you can use code in other answers if you use 1.9.

But I don't want to recommend to rely this behavior because it is implicit behavior and I'm afraid of future changes. Instead, use method yielding the hash entry in order of sum of length of strings.

```
def each_by_length(hash)
  hash = hash.sort_by { |_, strs| strs.map(&:length).inject(0, &:+) }
  hash.each do |k, v|
    yield k, v
  end
end
```