# Sorting of 2D Array by its amount of in the inner elements

Tags: ruby, sorting, multidimensional-array

How do I sort a 2D array by the length of its inner elements? The number of inner elements is not the same.

Example:

```
a = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

After sorting, the array will become:

```
#=> [[4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3], [8, 9], [1]]
```

Comment: Can you explain what have you tried? It would be nice of you if you demonstrate that at least you put some effort trying to resolve the problem.

Comment: Erm, Simone, I did tried.

Comment: The statement I placed was 
followers = followers.sort_by{|x| followers[0..followers.length-1].length}

Followers was my array, I have tried this but it does not seems to be sorting as to what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

This solution works:

```
a = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
a.sort_by! { |array| -array.length }
#=> [[4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [2, 3], [1]]
```

I am using the [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) method and sort by length from largest to smallest.

This solution is more readable and works as well, but it is a bit slower:

```
a = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
a.sort_by(&:length).reverse!
#=> [[4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [2, 3], [1]]
```

I am using the [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) method using length, which will sort the array from smallest to largest by length. Then I use the [`reverse!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse-21) method it to have it in order from largest to smallest.

Comment: In a case in which I want to preserve the index of the array, so I created an hash with the based on the index of the array, then I would like to sort the hash according to the length size which I have mentioned previously,  Does this statements work again with it?

Comment: @ZhenLiangLow I believe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957012/sort-hash-by-length-of-contained-values

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
a.sort { |x, y| y.size <=> x.size }
#=> [[4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3], [8, 9], [1]]
```

Comment: Ah I realised why I thought It was wrong! the sorting was correct

Comment: In a case in which I want to preserve the index of the array, so I created an hash with the based on the index of the array, then I would like to sort the hash according to the length size which I have mentioned previously,  Does this statements work again with it?